Differentiator op amp circuit does not give the expected result IRL
I built this setup on a breadboard:

R is 330k, C is 820nF.
I added a 11k resistor before C.
Op amp is KA358A. It is powered  by gnd / 3.3v
As a starting point, I used a triangle signal as input. Amplitude 600mV, freq 50Hz
I was expecting a positive value when the slope is descending but this is what I get:

Yellow: input.
orange: output.
I don't understand why...
Can you explain ?
Thanks


Output voltage swing is Vcc-1.5V
you have only a positive supply, but a negative ramp
your ramp results in something like a negative 3.6V output flipping to a positive 3.6V
in the negative side the opamp can not drive at all, thus you exceed the input voltage range
at 200kS/s it is hard to judge if the little rectangle is syncted with the triangle or not

So you exceed the output voltage swing (3V negative and ~1V positive), the input voltage swing and have your digital oscilloscope at a low sampling rate...

lower the rate/amplification
put a 1:1 voltage divider (moderate to high impedance) on the + input of the opamp to offset your signal to the middle of the supply range (and not to 0).


As opamp is supplied with 3.3V/0 V, you should use a "fix" voltage on "+input" of 1.65 V.
And fix also the voltage of the generator.
Here is an example with another opamp (rail to rail).
Made with microcap v12.
You should choose a "low" input frequency like 1 Hz.

With a frequency like 50 Hz, it is a "bit" different.

Here is the response with Bode behavior, which shows a limit frequency of ~ 10 Hz.

